# How to anchor a text artist to a legend artist?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I position a text artist relative to for example another text artist or a legend artist. Suppose I want to have some arbitrary text placed under the legend, but the legend will have a variable number of entries. Therefore the legend spans an unknown distance in the y dimension. Regardless of how large or small the legend gets to be, I want to position my text immediately below it.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as lines

plt.figure(figsize=(11., 8.5))
plt.gcf().add_axes([0.05,0.05,0.6,0.6])
bar=lines.Line2D([],[], color="0.1", linewidth=2,ls=":", marker="1")
plt.gca().legend([bar],["foo"],bbox_to_anchor=[1.,1.], loc="upper left")
s=r"$\alpha$"
s+=r"$\alpha_i \beta_j \gamma^k$"
plt.text(1.02,0.8,s,transform=plt.gca().transData, wrap =True, fontsize ="xx-small")
plt.show()
```

In this script I want to anchor the text artist to the bottom of the legend artist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am quite sure if you would search you would be able to find a few examples of how to do it.

Here is one way to do it:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11., 8.5))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.05,0.05,0.6,0.6])
bar=lines.Line2D([],[], color="0.1", linewidth=2,ls=":", marker="1")
leg = ax.legend([bar],["foo"],bbox_to_anchor=[1.,1.], loc="upper left")
s=r"$\alpha$"
s+=r"$\alpha_i \beta_j \gamma^k$"

# You need to draw the artists before you can get its coordinates:
plt.draw()

# Now get coordinates of the legend
p = leg.get_window_extent().inverse_transformed(ax.transAxes)

# Set offset of the text in 'axes fraction' units 
# (if it is 0 text will be placed within the legend box, set 'zorder=9' as parameter to ax.annotate to see it)
offset = 0.03

# Now place the text on the plot
ax.annotate('Annotation', (p.p0[0], p.p0[1] - offset), xycoords='axes fraction')

plt.show()
```

[image]